# Why does my Vue js app lose focus when routing to other components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a vuejs app that loses focus when the route is changed.  When the site loads the first element of the header component is in focus (perfect) which is what I want. However, when i navigate to any other link on the site and hit tab the focus never goes to the header component. 
If I remove the footer the page focuses on header component like it is supposed to.  When I add the footer the focus breaks?

I have tried focusing on another area before each component is destroyed (beforeDestroy) that didn't work.  I've also tried adding more divs to the template as well as focusing on the component but that didn't work.

Do I need to use a watcher?

My temporary solution is reloading the page twice and that works but very tacky as the API is being called twice.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**The router is being loading like this...**

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '/',    
  component: landingPage,  //works fine
  }, 
  { path: '/home', component: HomePage }, //does not load properly
  { path: '/search', component: SearchPage }, //does not load properly
  { path: '/about', component: AboutPage } //does not load properly
```

**Below is the template, and loading of components...**

```
<template>
 <div>
   <my-header/>
   <router-view  />
   <my-footer/>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import mylayout from 'my-layout'
import '../node_modules/my-layout/dist/my-layout.css'

export default {
 components: {
  'my-header': mylayout.components['my-header'],  
  'my-footer': mylayout.components['my-footer']
 },

name: 'app',
data: function () {
 return {
  state: 'initial'
 }
},


beforeCreate: function () {
 // `this` points to the vm instance
  console.log('app before create')
 },
created: function () {
 // `this` points to the vm instance
console.log('app created')
},
beforeMount: function () {
// `this` points to the vm instance
console.log('app before mount')
},
 mounted: function () {
 // `this` points to the vm instance
 console.log('app mounted')
},
beforeDestroy: function () {
 // `this` points to the vm instance
 console.log('app before destroy')
},
destroyed: function () {
// `this` points to the vm instance
console.log('app destroyed')
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems focus management is not Vue Router dev's priority right now. They acknowledge the limitations but [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2488) is pretty old and activity on it not that great.

You can try to solve this [by yourself](https://marcus.io/blog/accessible-routing-vuejs) or use [router library](https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-vue-router) tailored to solve exactly this issue....